# Why recatpcha gives an error (not read value) after about 1 minute in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha-v3

use  "react-google-recaptcha";

```
 const [reCapValue, setreCapValue] = useState(""); 
 function onChange(value: any) {
        console.log("Captcha value:", value);
        setreCapValue(value);
      }

  <div className="my-8">
      <ReCAPTCHA
        size="normal"
        sitekey="6Lfh89QhAAAAALc5nAEFIXMq95I3vWuyQiZiti83"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
  </div>
  <button
          type="submit"
          className={`${
            reCapValue.length > 0
              ? "bg-Color text-white"
              : "bg-gray-300"
          }
          rounded-md disabled:cursor-not-allowed`}
          disabled={reCapValue.length > 0 ? false : true}
        >
          Ok
        </button>
```

At first it does the validation but after a certain time it gives an error.
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length').

Comment: recaptcha has a session timeout.  Is it only valid for a short period of time for security reasons.

Comment: understand. So how can I do a validation as an alternative?